Relating Velocity to refractive index
First time posting so I'm sorry if I mess this up but, I am working on a project for work and I am wondering if you could relate the refractive index of a fluid to the velocity of the fluid as it moves through a pipe, provided you knew enough about the fluid (Temp, chemical make up, etc)? My idea was that if you knew the refractive index of a fluid while it was at rest and then measured the change in the refractive index while it was in motion you could find the velocity of the fluid. It could be that the refractive index wouldn't in that case the project would be scrapped. But if it can I am having trouble relating the velocity of the fluid to its refractive index.

What makes you think that the refractive index should change with velocity in the first place?

Welcome Jest Dennis to Physics Stack Exchange. You might want to clarify how you plan to measure the index of refraction. Are planning to do something like a Fizeau experiment? I also suggest looking at "Can light be dragged by fluid?" and "Refractive index of dielectric in different frames of reference".
